# Get frame/dimensions from SwiftUI view(s)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Let's assume, to present a specific piece of information I have two different kinds of custom SwiftUI views. For the sake of an example my data is two Strings and the options to display them is either in a

```
HStack { Text() Spacer() Text() }
```

or

```
VStack {
Text()
Text()
}
```

style. In order to select the *best fitting* one, I would need to render them and make a choice based on resulting dimensions. For instance, if one of the text views in the first style would approach 50% of the window size, I would rather go with the second style.

How would I go about this without the user seeing the temporary views?

I know about `GeometryReader`, but I don't know how I could render my "candidate views" *off screen*, determine sizes and then make a selection for my actual view hierarchy.

Any hints?

Comment: Whoa, why the downvote? If this is trivial to archive, I’ll happily accept a link to some documentation that I obviously overlooked.

Comment: Upvoted to cancel out the downvote, but it would be way easier to do something like `if UIScreen.main.bounds.width < 300 { compact layout }`

Comment: "determine sizes and then make a selection" this would be very hard to do, not just in SwiftUI, but how would you do this in UIKit?

Comment: For anyone seeking a solution: I ended up using `UILabel sizeThatFits` for now. Although that is not an answer to my question it is the best I could find.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to work properly with SwiftUI. However, the following is an approach for what you want using `UIKit` and `Labels` for text:

```
let max_width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width/2
if label.intrinsicContentSize.width > max_width{
    //The text would occupy more than 50% of the screen in width
}else{
    //The text won't occupy more than 50% of the screen in width
}
```

You would have to run the previous function on each `Label` and there you can decide.

I know this is not a complete answer because you are working with SwiftUI, but someone may know how to apply the previous code on there.